# How to route all the Windows traffic into WSL2?

Tags: windows, routing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to route all traffic from Windows to WSL2 (172.28.20.4), but I have little knowledge about networking.

I did try to add a route:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 172.28.20.4
```

I also enabled IP forwarding in WSL2 and I ran this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Which produce :

```
Network destination Network mask Adr. gateway Adr. Metric interface
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.37     35
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.28.20.4      172.28.16.1   5001
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      172.28.16.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.28.16.1   5256
      172.28.16.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.16.1   5256
    172.28.31.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.16.1   5256
     172.28.192.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.28.192.1   5256
     172.28.192.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.28.192.1   5256
   172.28.207.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.28.192.1   5256
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.37    291
     192.168.1.37  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.37    291
```

The problem is that eth0 (172.28.20.4) is behind a NAT so if I remove:

```
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.37     35
```

I wouldnt be able to access internet anymore.

Comment: What's the goal here? This would be easily possible with a full Hyper-V VM running Linux, but probably a headache with WSL2...

Comment: @u1686_grawity I want that all Windows traffic is redirected to WSL2 such that Multi-Path TCP is "enabled" in Windows and could profit of the multiple use of network interfaces. I think there is better options like using OpenVPN Client in Windows and running an OpenVPN  server on WSL right ?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Also please, can u show me how to do it in a full Hyper-V VM running Linux, this may maybe help me, since I can add network interfaces by myself using WSLAttachSwitch.

Comment: Ahh, I don't think that'll make MP-TCP work – as far as I know, the _endpoints_ must understand it; it's not something that can be injected by a gateway/router. I'll post an answer, but I don't think it will actually help your goal.

Comment: I am guessing this isn't route want but instead listen want?   What would be best is just add kali and have it listen easily to parse and understand or get evil with... or let me talk more about something else in an answer... (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work with the default configuration of WSL2, as the system is set up to *route WSL2's traffic through the host* – your host OS is the 'default gateway' for WSL2 – so all you get this way is a routing loop.

The simplest way to make it work would be to add a second network interface for the VM – in Hyper-V Virtual Switch terminology you need to create an "External" vSwitch, which gives VMs direct access to the physical LAN. Then your physical gateway via the 2nd interface should be set as the VM's s default gateway.

I would really suggest using a "full" Hyper-V VM for this, as you'll be able to configure things without fighting with WSL's automation: you just create the virtual switches, assign them to the VM, and it'll *stay* that way. (Plus, Hyper-V VMs are designed to automatically run in background, and their guest OS will have a fully working service manager (init system) straight out of the box.)

Finally, I don't think any of this will actually let you use MP-TCP from Windows. That's something that TCP itself needs to understand – meaning, the *endpoints* of the connection must understand it – it is not something that can be injected by a gateway, unless that gateway becomes a full-on TCP proxy (which is not something that a router/gateway normally does).

Answer (score 0):

You may want an actual nic and not IP but a device so you would need to buy an incredibly cheap usb wifi or cheaper usb nic and then PLUG it in directly to WSL minus windows sorta... so after getting device visit https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win

after that you wouldn't use windows IPs etc if that is what you actually wanted.  You would have 2 separate nics one for each computer.